# where statement using variable

Tags: sql

I have a small problem in retrieving characters using user variable in SQL
The query is as follows

```
DECLARE @search
SET @search='chicken'

SELECT * from Recipes where TITLE like '@search'
```

IS this correct? It should retrieve the recipes where Title contains the word which is given to @search.

I even tried giving

```
SELECT * from Recipes where TITLE IN ('+@search+')
SELECT * from Recipes where TITLE =@search
SELECT * from Recipes where TITLE =$[@search]
```

But none seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
set @search='chicken'

select * from recipes where title like '%' + @search + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using `SQL Server` because of undelimited query, concatenate the variable with `%` so you will get title containing the keyword you search

```
DECLARE @search
SET @search='chicken'

SELECT * from Recipes where TITLE like '%' + @search + '%'
```